# How much fuel does an A380 hold and where?

Tags: wing, airbus-a380, fuel-tanks

How much fuel does an A380 usually carry (in litres) and what is the maximum? How much is in each wing? How much is in other fuel tanks and where are they?

Comment: I think this question qualifies for "*this question doesn't show any [research effort](https://www.google.com/search?complete=0&q=a380+tanks+capacity&oq=a380+tanks+capacity)*" and could be downvoted.

Comment: The "where" part is answered here: [Is the entire length of a B747 or A380 wing used as a fuel tank?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/48426/1696)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The total capacity of fuel tanks of Airbus A380 is [320000 liters](http://www.airbus.com/aircraft/passenger-aircraft/a380-family/technology.html).

The fuel tanks in Airbus A380 are shown in this image.

[image: tanks]
<sup>*[Image Source](https://captaindave.aero/2017/09/07/the-a380-fuel-system/)*</sup>

The capacities of different tanks are<sup>1</sup> (in liters):

- Tail tank: 23,698
- Inner tanks: 90,600
- Mid tanks: 72,000
- Feed tank 2 and 3: 28,130 each
- Feed tank 1 and 4: 26,974 each
- Outer tanks: 9,524 each

---

<sup>1</sup> *The only place I found this information is in the book [Airbus A380: Superjumbo of the 21st Century](http://a.co/hWB6fSU). Luckily, it is on [Google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=PUYTd4DST2AC&lpg=PA122&ots=Yo9x_3h-4i&dq=airbus%20a380%20outer%20tank&pg=PA118#v=onepage&q&f=false). This excerpt from the book about the relevant information says:*

> The horizontal stabilizer runs through section 19 and includes an integral fuel tank between ribs 8 left and right. The fuel level in the tail tank, which can take up to 23,698 liters, is adjustable in flight for trimming purposes. Overall, the hard-line A380-800 fuel-tank capacity is 315,292 liters, most of which is contained in two inner tanks with more than 90,600 liters. Two other mid-tanks hold about 72,000 liters between them, with inner engine 2 and 3 feed tanks containing 28,130 liters each. The outer engine 1 and 4 feed tanks each hold 26,974 liters, while the two outer tanks each hold 9,524 liters.

Comment: Just to complete the information, that is the configuration for an A380-800. If the -900 and -1000 were done and not abandoned, they will have center tanks (2 of them) in the central box of the wings.